# Filter columns by the percentile of values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter out columns with 'many' zero values in pandas.
It is not difficult to filter columns consist of 'all zero values', but what I want to do is filter columns with 'many zero values', for example, more than 75% of the column values.

Dataset (A has 3 zeros of 4 values, which is 75% of the column values.)

```
A B C
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 2 3
```

Result

```
B C
0 0
0 1 
1 2
2 3
```

Are there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension , `sum` function and `drop` i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,1],'b':[0,0,1,1],'c':[1,1,0,1]})
mask = [i for i,j in enumerate((df == 0).astype(int).sum(axis=0).values)  if (j/df.shape[0])>=0.75]
df = df.drop(df.columns[mask], axis=1)
```

You can set the percentile as you like.

Output : if 75 percentile i.e `(j/df.shape[0])>=0.75`

```
 
   b  c
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1
```

Output : if 50 percentile i.e `(j/df.shape[0])>=0.50`

```
   c
0  1
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

Comment: Using enumerate function to make the mask seems to be a nice idea, though it was a little bit difficult for me to understand the structure. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) of `boolean mask`, where `True` values are converted to `1`, and then invert condition - `>=` to `<` for filter all columns with less `mean` as `0.75`:

```
print ((df == 0).mean())
a    0.75
b    0.50
c    0.25
dtype: float64

print ((df == 0).mean() < 0.75)
a    False
b     True
c     True
dtype: bool

df = df.loc[:, (df == 0).mean() < 0.75]
print (df)
   b  c
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1
```

Comment: This is really nice answer +1

Comment: It's very nice and intuitive to use mean for this task. Thank you for your answer.